# NLTK regexp tokenization to spaCy conversion not working

Tags: python, regex, nltk, spacy, tokenize

We have code, written in NLTK, but we need it in spaCy, because we are trying to improve the speed with help of CUDA cores.

Here is the NLTK code:

```
import nltk
import re
import time

snt1 = u'''"{'body': 'So as of today&#39;s close (8/15/14), I&#39;m long $TSLA $AMTD $TWTR $FB $AAPL $CELG - all on a longer-term, technical swing long basis.', 'conversation': None, 'created_at': '2014-08-15T20:03:03Z', 'entities': {'chart': None, 'sentiment': None}, 'id': 25816362.0, 'liked_by_self': False, 'likes': {'total': 2.0, 'user_ids': array([373042, 346110])}, 'links': None, 'mentioned_users': array([], dtype=object), 'reshared_by_self': False, 'source': {'id': 1.0, 'title': 'Stocktwits', 'url': 'https://stocktwits.com'}, 'symbols': array([{'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 686, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'AAPL', 'title': 'Apple Inc.', 'watchlist_count': 318737},
       {'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 861, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'AMTD', 'title': 'TD AMERITRADE Holding Corporation', 'watchlist_count': 2938},
       {'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 1260, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'CELG', 'title': 'Celgene Corporation', 'watchlist_count': 17553},
       {'aliases': array(['FBOOK'], dtype=object), 'id': 7871, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'FB', 'title': 'Facebook', 'watchlist_count': 228228},
       {'aliases': array(['TWIT'], dtype=object), 'id': 7872, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'TWTR', 'title': 'Twitter', 'watchlist_count': 144188},
       {'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 8660, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'TSLA', 'title': 'Tesla, Inc.', 'watchlist_count': 234613}],
      dtype=object), 'user': {'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.stocktwits.com/production/148175/thumb-1430958785.png', 'avatar_url_ssl': 'https://avatars.stocktwits.com/production/148175/thumb-1430958785.png', 'classification': array(['suggested'], dtype=object), 'followers': 19514.0, 'following': 198.0, 'id': 148175.0, 'ideas': 13994.0, 'identity': 'User', 'join_date': '2012-04-05', 'like_count': 4618.0, 'name': 'Jake Huska', 'official': False, 'plus_tier': '', 'premium_room': '', 'username': 'MarketPicker', 'watchlist_stocks_count': 25.0}}"'''

def tokenize(snt1):
    
    start1 = time.time()
    
    token_list=nltk.regexp_tokenize(snt1, pattern=r"\s|[\.,;]\D", gaps=True)
    
    stop1 = time.time()
    t1 = str(stop1 - start1)
    print('Tokenize input snt1 into token - '+ t1 +' sekund.')
    
    return(token_list)

tokenize(snt1)
```

We would like to get the same result with spaCy, but we just can't get the code right. We would be very greateful if someone, that knows how to do that would help to find us the solution.

Here is our spaCy code, that doesn't make exactly the same result as NLTK code does:

```
import re
import time
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
spacy.prefer_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

start4 = time.time()

snt1 = u'''"{'body': 'So as of today&#39;s close (8/15/14), I&#39;m long $TSLA $AMTD $TWTR $FB $AAPL $CELG - all on a longer-term, technical swing long basis.', 'conversation': None, 'created_at': '2014-08-15T20:03:03Z', 'entities': {'chart': None, 'sentiment': None}, 'id': 25816362.0, 'liked_by_self': False, 'likes': {'total': 2.0, 'user_ids': array([373042, 346110])}, 'links': None, 'mentioned_users': array([], dtype=object), 'reshared_by_self': False, 'source': {'id': 1.0, 'title': 'Stocktwits', 'url': 'https://stocktwits.com'}, 'symbols': array([{'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 686, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'AAPL', 'title': 'Apple Inc.', 'watchlist_count': 318737},
       {'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 861, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'AMTD', 'title': 'TD AMERITRADE Holding Corporation', 'watchlist_count': 2938},
       {'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 1260, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'CELG', 'title': 'Celgene Corporation', 'watchlist_count': 17553},
       {'aliases': array(['FBOOK'], dtype=object), 'id': 7871, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'FB', 'title': 'Facebook', 'watchlist_count': 228228},
       {'aliases': array(['TWIT'], dtype=object), 'id': 7872, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'TWTR', 'title': 'Twitter', 'watchlist_count': 144188},
       {'aliases': array([], dtype=object), 'id': 8660, 'is_following': False, 'symbol': 'TSLA', 'title': 'Tesla, Inc.', 'watchlist_count': 234613}],
      dtype=object), 'user': {'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.stocktwits.com/production/148175/thumb-1430958785.png', 'avatar_url_ssl': 'https://avatars.stocktwits.com/production/148175/thumb-1430958785.png', 'classification': array(['suggested'], dtype=object), 'followers': 19514.0, 'following': 198.0, 'id': 148175.0, 'ideas': 13994.0, 'identity': 'User', 'join_date': '2012-04-05', 'like_count': 4618.0, 'name': 'Jake Huska', 'official': False, 'plus_tier': '', 'premium_room': '', 'username': 'MarketPicker', 'watchlist_stocks_count': 25.0}}"'''


text = snt1

nlp.tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, token_match=re.compile(r"\s|[\.,;]\D").match)
list1 = []
for tok in nlp(text):
    list1.append(tok.text)

stop4 = time.time()
t1 = str(stop4 - start4)
print('Tokenize input snt1 into token - '+t1+' sekund.')
list1
```

Kind Regards,
Primoz

Comment: text = sentence
do you mean text = snt1?

Comment: Yes, I mean text = snt1, thank You! I already made the corrections for the mistakes you found.

Comment: Can I may ask what are you trying to achieve ? I ran the code(NLTK one) and just go a split of words ,I got the same result as doing snt1.split()